# Ruby on android.Termux

Tags: android, ruby, termux

How do I run Ruby scripts in the Termux terminal? I only know how to activate IRB.

Answer (score 0):

You need root access for this.  Once you do, create your ruby script in the Termux directory (which may be in "/data/data/"-- you need root access to make sure).  Then just run `ruby rubyscript.rb` in the terminal.